# SharePoint not allowing json files

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I'm uploading an application to my SharePoint website but it doesn't allow json files that the application needs to function properly. Is there a way to bypass this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Central Administration`, navigate to `Manage Web Applications`. Highlight the Web Application you're uploading to, then click on `Blocked File Types` in the ribbon. Find the file type, in this case `json`, and remove it, then click OK. That should allow you to upload `json` files, unless there are restrictions imposed elsewhere (e.g. IIS Request Filtering).

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint 2013, JSON format is blocked from Central Admin. Below is the list of blocked format (by default) in SharePoint 2013:
[Manage Blocked F](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262496.aspx)

There are two work around for this problem.

**First one:**

> 1. Verify that you have the following administrative credentials. 
>         --You must be a farm administrator on the server.
> 2. In Central Administration, click Security. 3  On the Security page, in the General Security section, click Define blocked file types.
> 3. On the Blocked File Types page, if you want to change the selected web application, on the Web Application menu, click Change Web
>      Application. Use the Select Web Application page to select a web
>      application.
> 4. To stop blocking a file type, select a file type from the list, press the Delete key, and then click OK.

**Second Method:**

You can create an application page, with function declared as **WebMethod**.
This method can return JSON format response. As extension for application page will be "aspx", which won't be blocked, and you may call that method like this:

> http://server-name/application-page-url/methodName